# Compensating transaction in ASP.NET Core Web API and cosmos DB in monolith application

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-cosmosdb

I have API and UI projects. In API project we have a POST endpoint that is designed to accept a list, which then writes them as document to Cosmos DB.

When a UI sends less than 1000 items in a request to POST endpoint, API endpoint processing it without errors. These items are saved in a sequence using `DbContext` object from EF Core.

Now, I want to change post method to process more than 1000 items in a request.

Here catch is I have requirement to either succeed all items else failed and restore to original data was existed in DB before update.

I am using EF Core, .NET 6, Cosmos DB and React for UI

What I have tried:

`TransactionalBatch` option which is good choice.

Limitations

1. Supports 100 records per batch, I am unable to handle compensate transaction scenario.
2. We have partition key that is not matching for `TransactionalBatch` hence it is updating record by record.

Cosmos DB stored procedure is another option:

1. Same partition key is constraint that is not matching for our design.

Custom logic: all items before update, I can keep original data from DB to mem/redis cache, then I will try updating records in case of failure I can use mem/redis cache to compensate back.